# Spring WebClient randomly got connection reset by peer when access aws API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I use Webclient to access AWS API GATEWAY to mock oauth2 token and API. The webclient randomly got connection reset by peer. it works for several minutes and suddenly lose connection,then recover in some minutes.

Also check some webclient configuration try to disabled connection pool or set the idle time both not wok.

Check to connect postman server, it works well so i think it related to API gateway,but didn't find any issue.

the API gateway configuration are HTTP API with two routs one is for oauth token the other is API. Both use lambda to return value. Does anyone knows why this issue happen.Or how can i investigate the issue